# How to occupy another containers space?

Tags: html, css

So this is my first project please bear with me, I have been stuck for hours trying to figure out how to get my registration text to be in the center of the screen, I think my login text is occupying the whole screen so it automatically drops my registration text to the lower half. I have included the image of the idea.

Here is my HTML:

```
        <div class="main">
            <div class="main_container">
                <div class="main_content">
                    <h1>Stock IO </h1>
                    <h2>Already A User?</h2>
                    <p>Sign In Below</p>
                    <button class="main_btn_register"><a href="/login.html">Login</a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main_register">
            <div class="main_container_register">
                <div class="main_content_register">
                    <h1>Welcome To Stock IO</h1>
                    <h2>Register Below To Gain Full Access To Our Site</h2>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="main_img_register-container">
                    <img src="img/signup.svg" alt="pic" id="main_img_signup">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Heres my css for both the login container and the registration container ignore the mobile

```
/*Login Section*/
.main {
background-color: #141414;
}

.main_container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: ifr ifr;
    align-items: top;
    justify-self: top;
    text-align: left;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: #141414;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 0 50px;


}

.main_content h1 {

font-size: 3rem;
background-color: #ff8177;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
background-size: 100%;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-moz-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-moz-text-fill-color: transparent;







}

.main_content h2 {

font-size: 1rem;
background-color: #ff8177;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
background-size: 100%;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-moz-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-moz-text-fill-color: transparent;



}

.main_content p{

    margin-top: 4rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #c54c4c;

}

.main_btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
    padding: 14px 32px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    outline: none;

}

.main_btn a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main_btn::after{

    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #4837ff ;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

.main_btn:hover {

    color: #fff

}

.main_btn:hover:after {
width: 100%;
}

.main_img-container {

text-align: center;
}

#main_img {
    height: 30%;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

````
/*mobile responsive ignore*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
    .main_container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        align-items: center;
        justify-self: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 90vh;
    }

    .main_content {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;

    }

    .main_content h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        margin-top: 2rem;

    }

    .main_content h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .main_content p {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    
    .main_content h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-top: 3rem;

    }

    .main_content h2 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .main_content p {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    } 

    .main_btn {
        padding: 12px 36px;
        margin: 2.5rem 0;
    }

}
``` ```    /* Register Headers*/

.main_register { 
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
    
    .main_container_register {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: ifr ifr;
        align-items: top;
        justify-self: center;
        text-align: center;
        height: 80vh;
        background-color: #141414;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 3200px;
        padding: 0 50px;
    
    }
    
    
    .main_content_register h1 {
    
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    
    
    }
    
    .main_content_register h2 {
    
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    
    
    
    }
    
    .main_content_register p{
    
        margin-top: 4rem;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #fff;
    
    }```
````

Comment: You mention including and image of your idea, but I don't see that here.